# How to write a LoadRunner script to measure queue depth for JMS?

Tags: jms, loadrunner

I need to write a loadRunner script to measure the queue depth per second for JMS. Can anyone give tips on achieving this using LR v12.5?

Many Thanks!
Anuradha

Answer (score 0):

First, ask yourself, how would you manually examine the queue depth for your queue provider?  for instance, if your queue is a queue table on ORACLE, then you would simply query the number of rows in the queue table.  If your queue is on RabbitMQ, then perhaps you would use the management plug in to issue an HTTP request with the appropriate parameters for queue depth.  For MQ you might have a command line option from the system prompt.

Once you understand the manual method then you can look at how you automate this either at the GUI layer or at the protocol layer for the queue provider.   The manual process plus the communications architecture for the back end queue provider is the key here.